# Does AWS CloudFormation StacksSets support creating quick links like CloudFormation Stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

AWS Documentation clearly states the support of quick links for CloudFormation Stacks [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-create-stacks-quick-create-links.html#cfn-console-create-stacks-quick-create-links-example) through which we can automatically populate the template's parameters. But I couldn't find any similar official AWS Documentation or any other resources for supporting quick links in CloudFormation StackSets. Is it currently unsupported? Or do we have any workaround available for StackSets? I'm primarily trying to populate the values in CloudFormation Template for StackSets.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can automate it using a regular stack, the stack will define the StackSet's parameters:

- See: [Automate CloudFormation StackSets](https://cloudonaut.io/automate-cloudformation-stacksets-with-cloudformation/)

Then, you can use the "Stack quick link" feature.

Hope it helps.